# Class as unionOf but without this other classes being disjoint

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have a class A with two subclasses B and C, and I want to say that A is the union of B and C. But B and C are not disjoint, so I can't use `Disjoint Union Of` in Protege.

What is the correct way of doing this? And `Equivalent To` with and `and`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xjld.png

Comment: thanks @StanislavKralin feel free to leave it as an answer. It end ups being an `Equivalent to` with an `or`, so that's where I was wrong

Comment: You could also declare `A subclassOf (B or C)`, the equivalence will be inferred.